# elementor development - custom widget like an inner section widget

Tags: plugins, themes, widgets

I want to create a custom widget like an inner section widget, this custom widget is almost like an inner section widget.

the problem is I can't find a reference to the elementor website developer, has anyone ever made it? can you help me provide a reference

thanks.

Comment: Did you mean you can't find the Elementor developer documentation? https://developers.elementor.com/ But you would probably need to ask Elementor directly about this.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I've read the documentation and I can't find the answer to my question. yeah might try to contact Elementor